# Making a section of HTML and CSS responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My website is completely responsive at the moment (the layout, the pictures etc), with one issue. There's a section of my code which I'm not sure how to make responsive. Here's `code` I want to make responsive: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnaeaxge/14/)

I'd like it so it resizes like the rest of the website. 
If anyone has any ideas, I'd be grateful!

Cheers

**HTML &CSS:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
html 
  color: #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.description {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.7);
}

div, img, footer {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 36pt;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 24pt;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18pt;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 14pt;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

p {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-bottom: 12pt;
  margin-right: 12px;
  margin-left: 12px;

}

strong {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

a {
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dff3fd;
}
a:visited {
  color: #dff3fd;
}
li.active a, a:hover, a:active {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered-y {
  position: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.distribution-map {
  position: relative;
  width: 1190px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.distribution-map > img {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.distribution-map .map-point {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s; 
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s; 
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s, 0.25s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, width 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, z-index 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s; 
  background: rgba(26, 26, 26, 0.85);
  border: 3px solid #dff3fd;
}
.distribution-map .map-point .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: overlay;
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  width: 550px;
  height: 400px;
  color: #e5e5e5;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, width 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out; 
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s, 0s, 0s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.25s, height 0.25s ease-in-out, overflow 0.25s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:active .content a:active, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:hover, .distribution-map .map-point:focus .content a:active {
  color: #dff3fd;
}
        </style>
 </head>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<div class="distribution-map">


    <button class="map-point" style="top:24%;left:26.5%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>details</p>
              <iframe width="350" height="197" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5MgBikgcWnY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:26%;left:49%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
   <button class="map-point" style="top:27.3%;left:71.4%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:63.5%;left:31.5%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another one</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <button class="map-point" style="top:65%;left:56%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>another one</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
     <button class="map-point" style="top:68%;left:74%">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="centered-y">
                <h2>Another</h2>
                <p>Details...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using absolute and relative positioning here? Is there a reason you had to take the dots out of the normal flow of the document?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use percentages to make everything responsive. Media queries is not always enough. I suggest to forget about pixels. Even for font-size. All you need to do is change base pixel (body) size for font-size instead of every h1,h2 etc. Modern applications use as less pixels as possible.

In your case if you want your circles responsible at all times use `width: 100%` in your `distrubution-map.` Also for `.distribution-map .map-point:active,
.distribution-map .map-point:focus, .distribution-map .map-point:hover` I have `width: 50%` for example which will take 50% width of your screen at all times, this way your get responsive design.

Answer on other questions:
@Joe this is how it looks like 1em = 100% ≈ 12pt ≈ 16px. Ofc if you have something else for example 20px in body (or browser default px -> depends on browser) and you make your h1 150% you will get 30px for example (children adopt the size). That's great when you use media queries. You only need to change px in body and the rest just adapts. As for width and height of your borders, you need to have some normalizer or reset (or change to 0px yourself) otherwise you also have default borders. That's why 40% + 60% width can be higher then 100% in css. Another problem is that margins act weird. margin-top will change if you resize in width... Not in height. I use just top as much as possible since that one resizes only when you change height of your window. The best way to start is designing for mobile first. (progressive enhancement) I suggest to read about all of this in head first mobile web

Comment: Thanks for the answer PVL. The way I get these things to the size I want (like specifying pixels), would I just experiment with the percentages to find the right size? Cheers

Comment: @Joe See answer above, too long for a comment section.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's just one single setting that needs to be changed:

```
.distribution-map {
  width: 100%;
}
```

(instead of a fixed width)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Johannes. I'm still finding that when I set that width to 100% it the circles, when expanded still go off the screen. Cheers